# What are the alternatives for file upload on ios safari?

Tags: ios, web, mobile-website, dropbox-api, icloud-api

I have a mobile web app/site and I would like the users to upload a word document to our site.

As safari on the iPhone is not able to upload files what are the alternatives?

I have seen http://code.google.com/p/iphone-photo-picker/ however this is not photograph.

Is it documented anywhere that the Dropbox API, iCloud API or another API would allow selection a file from a user to copy to our servers?

Alternately is there another way for our iPhone users using safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, iPhone does not offer input type file on it's browser (except for images or videos).

What i do is, have users to send file(s) via email to site and download it programmatically on the server side and assign it to user's account either according to email address or some sort of password in the email.

Answer (score 1):

Investigation has shown that the drop box API for the user so select a via on the webpage using OAuth could be an option in the future.

However the [dropbox api documentation](http://www.dropbox.com/developers/web_docs) at the time of writing says:

> Web applications using the Dropbox API are currently not officially
>   supported.

[iCloud API](http://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php) is in beta and only available to members of the iOS and Mac Developer Programs so I am unable to review it's possibilities.

---

**Update:** I have now found this site: http://filepicker.io that handles uploads from facebook and dropbox.